# How to categorize build failures with jenkins?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, build-automation

I am looking for a solution that would allow us to categorize build failures like:

- developer (a developer added bad code)
- build system (error in the build system)
- infrastructure problem (servers not responding)

It would be great if this could be done **automatically most of the time**, based on the console output but also we need an option to make a build to be of certain status.

How can we obtain this behaviour from jenkins?

Comment: Is your question that (1) you already have a mechanism to determine failure causes and are only looking for ways to report them properly or (2) that you are looking for ways of implementing such a mechanism?

Comment: Let's say that I could implement the failure detection myself, but I need to find a way of storing the failure reason in jenkins database. If nothing like this exists, I would accept a set of hints on how to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

The [Build Failure Analyzer plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer) lets you set regular expressions for categorizing current and future builds. Once the regular expressions have been set, detection is automatic for current and future builds. This may be exactly what you're after.

I have also implemented a lightweight, manual failure categorization plug-in for Jenkins, which provides a simple drop-down and additional text field for categorizing failures by hand. This was done for a research project studying build failures. Categorizations are currently saved as separate XMLs in each build's directory, to have no impact on Jenkins' own files. Categories are displayed in build listings and in a separate categorization page for each build.

[image: Lightweight Jenkins plugin for manual failure categorization]

I regret to say that the plugin is not currently shared anywhere, as it contains some hard-codings for a specific project. If there is demand for such a plug-in, I can re-visit the code and publish it open source. However, for your purposes it seems like the automatic solution of Build Failure Analyzer would be more suitable.

The plug-in is very simple and similar things are not hard to implement. If you wish to make something similar yourself, or perhaps extend the automated Build Failure Analyzer plug-in to fit your needs, the [Jenkins plugin tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial) and [Extend Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extend+Jenkins) pages are a good starting point for Jenkins plug-in development. For persistence, getting familiar with [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) would be beneficial, as that is what Jenkins and most plug-ins internally use to serialize data to XML.

Comment: You should share so of your code! GitHub Gist is an option - just add a link in comments here. I need to figure out which tests are failing most often. Build Failure Analyzer allows to identify the build failures, but then I need to do some stats on the failures. Say, over the past week we had A failing X time, B failing Y times, C failing Y times, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For reporting purposes you can use *build description* (to edit it manually in order to see how it works go to `http://[jenkins_server]/job/[job_name]/[build_number]/editDescription`, or click on 'add description' on the build status page).

Programmatically you can set via [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) (**set-build-description** command); or from Groovy via Jenkins [Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/) - [Run::setDescription()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#setDescription%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Groovy scripts can be invoked either via [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) or [Groovy PostBuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin), or both.

Answer (score 1):

This tool I worked on, might help you: https://github.com/nacuteodor/SearchInJenkinsLogs . This can be integrated with a Jenkins job. You can find a searched text specifying a regular expression in builds artifacts, or tests failures and it will print the build nodes and failed tests reports links sorted by build and tests. Also, it has a feature to group the common similar failures using a maximum difference threshold, sorted by group failures count.

You could use this tool for finding crashes in artifacts logs, that you would like to be reported and fixed a.s.a.p, and you can make the job sent an email notification or fail the tool job build. I will might add some other features in the future.